# Internet explorer 11 browser cannot display the expires value of the session cookie from my app

Tags: internet-explorer, session-cookies

I'm currently testing my app by running it on IE11, Chrome and Firefox. Chrome and Firefox can display the value of the cookie.

[image: Using firefox]

IE11 displays the cookie name and its value, but failed to display other details like domain, path, expires etc.

My concern here is that after the user logs in successfully, he/she will be able to see the home (private) page but after 15-30 seconds will be kicked to the login page. And I think the problem has something to do with that cookie.

I used Developer tools of IE11 to debug.

**My questions are:**

1. What does it mean if IE11 couldn't display other details of the
   cookie? What are the possible reasons why IE11 could not display the
   details?
2. Am I right that the app is not behaving properly because of that
   issue with cookie?
3. What else can I do to investigate? Or what probably can fix the
   issue?

> Please also note that I've tried to open other known application in IE11 (gmail) and it was able to display all the cookie details. I think that implies that the browser is doing well, and that the problem might be on my side.

I recently found an [article regarding losing cookie information](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/810700/subject-ie11-is-losing-cookie-information-and-thus-becoming-detached-from-a-web-application-session) is it related to my problem?

Please enlighten me, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1) If you're using developer tools of IE, you wouldn't be able to see all the details about the cookie (I don't know why) but that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. I used a tool called [IECookiesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/iecookies.html) and it showed me all the details about the cookie.

2-3) After further research, I found out that my app isn't working properly because of the time difference. The server time settings is UTC +00:00 while the user's time setting is UTC +08:00. When I changed the time settings of the user and made it similar with the server's the app worked properly. For browsers like Chrome and Mozilla, they can handle it even if I don't make any changes with the time settings (don't know why), IE can't.

Here's the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416241/set-cookie-expire-property-clock-skew-and-internet-explorer-issue) that helped me understand the problem.