# Form does not submit in IE11 when privacy is set to 'always allow session cookies' unchecked, but works in IE10 and others

Tags: iframe, asp-classic, internet-explorer-11

**Scenario:**
I have two web applications A and B. A integrates application B in itself via iframe. Application A authenticates a user from B and maintains auth token in a session variable. Now, when application B is rendered on iframe on A and a login page appears, I submit the form and redirect to login but session becomes null. Remember Application A creates a session before redirecting to Login page.

This issue appears in case of IE11 only and when I set its **privacy settings -> always allow session cookies on it works**.... strange! isn't it.

[image]

**Check override automatic cookies and then check Always allow session cookies**  in IE11 and its works fine. However, the same thing works in IE10 without any issue. Any help regarding this.I am already looking into other questions with following links

[IE11 does not send session cookie when a link targeting a new tab is clicked (on first request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031602/ie11-does-not-send-session-cookie-when-a-link-targeting-a-new-tab-is-clicked-on)

[IE 11 first-party session cookies being lost in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384819/ie-11-first-party-session-cookies-being-lost-in-iframe)

[Does ie11 ignore cookies from site that uses the server's ip as domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729480/does-ie11-ignore-cookies-from-site-that-uses-the-servers-ip-as-domain)

[IE11 does not send session cookie when a link targeting a new tab is clicked (on first request)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031602/ie11-does-not-send-session-cookie-when-a-link-targeting-a-new-tab-is-clicked-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Issue was with the IE11 privacy policy as it was destroying session cookies for iframe. As I mentioned above it was working by tweaking its privacy settings.
Set P3P policy on IIS for your hosting site and issue is fixed, now this will ignore IE11 privacy policies