# Setting cookie expiry date in IE11

Tags: javascript, cookies, momentjs, internet-explorer-11

I am using moment.js to set the expiration date of my cookie (`expires` variable). The code below works fine in Chrome but IE11 and Edge just will not set the expiry date on the cookie

```
var nowDate = new Date();
        var creationDate = moment(nowDate);
        var expiresDate = moment(nowDate).utc();
        expiresDate.add(exdays, "d");
        var expires = "expires=" + expiresDate.toDate();
```

Everything I have read talks about IE11 expectign UTC format but even though I UTC() the moment object, IE11 is still not setting an expiry date

Answer (score 0):

1) If you're using developer tools of IE, you wouldn't be able to see all the details about the cookie (I don't know why) but that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. I used a tool called IECookiesView and it showed me all the details about the cookie.

2-3) After further research, I found out that my app isn't working properly because of the time difference. The server time settings is UTC +00:00 while the user's time setting is UTC +08:00. When I changed the time settings of the user and made it similar with the server's the app worked properly. For browsers like Chrome and Mozilla, they can handle it even if I don't make any changes with the time settings (don't know why), IE can't.

Here's the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416241/set-cookie-expire-property-clock-skew-and-internet-explorer-issue) that helped me understand the problem.